# In my footer how do I split in 2 rows the social icons when my screen width is less than 700 px?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries, font-awesome

I have 6 social site icons in my footer, with flexbox I put all in the same line.
I want them to change and split in 2 different rows (3 up and 3 down) when my screen arrives to 700px (Media Queries)

HTML:

```
<footer id="footer">
<div class="footer-socials">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer-socials{
  background-color: #196b19;
  width: 100%;
  }

.fa-youtube-square, .fa-facebook-square, .fa-instagram, .fa-vk, .fa- 
twitter-square, .fa-linkedin {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

ul, li{
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Please note: I gave the value "flex-direction: column" to my ID Footer because I have a multi level footer, the other footer is the 'legal' one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

in your icon div.

Comment: Doing this you could also add a max-width to that div if you wanted to ensure 3 top and 3 bottom.